# Does a "-" on guitar tab mean "play that string open"?

Tags: guitar, notation, tablature

I'm not a guitarist, I'm learning piano and I'm trying to translate some guitar tab for piano.

With this section of tab (for *I Don't Want It* by Ween, from the Ultimate Guitar site):

```
e--8-8-8---3-3----3-3-3-3-3-3---4-4--|
B--9-9-9---4-4----4-4-4-1-1-1---4-4--|
G--8-8-8---3-3----3-3-3-1-1-1---x-x--|
D-------------------------------3-3--|
A-------------------------------4-4--|
E------------------------------------|
```

At the start, the D A & E strings just have a "-".  Does that mean you **don't play** those strings, or does it mean you **play them open**?

Sometimes I've seen tab where the open strings are represented by having a "0", but I'm guessing that the convention may be to omit these as it makes the tab too cluttered and hard to read. Later on in that tab section there's an x on the G string, which I'm guessing means to mute the string.

That kind of suggests that we **are** supposed to play the E, A and D strings at the start, otherwise they would have x's too?  But I think this is one of those things that is ruled by convention rather than logic necessarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "don't play".

`0` is open.

In your case, the `8-9-8` at the beginning is a Ab major triad, that would clash a lot with the open E and A strings ^^

Comment: Strictly speaking, not so! 'Let ring', maybe. But that doesn't account for the dashes *before* the numbers...

Comment: Thanks.  That makes my life easier :)  I guess I could have worked this out by trying to play all of the notes (including the unmarked strings) on piano and seeing if it sounded awful .   So, i guess the difference between "-" and "x" is that when the string you don't want to play is in the middle of some strings you do want to play, you have to mute that string since you can't simply **avoid** hitting it on a strum, which you can do if you only need to play the top three strings?

Comment: @Tim i think the dashes before the numbers are just spacing, as you suggest in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

x means don't play that string at all. o means play that string open.

The dashes are just spacers, presumably some kind of timing device (there are 36 'zones' in a 'bar'). And although this would be a good idea, I don't think it's employed here, as the guitar starts at the very beginning of the bar - the chords shown don't!

The dashes actually do not mean don't play. If we go by the track, the chord played *before* the dashes actually rings on, until the next chord. This is one (of many for me!) problem with this sort of tab - it doesn't give as much detail as 'proper' music, in that unless there are notes or their stems shown as well, unless one knows how the song goes, one cannot know how the timing goes. And if one knows the song, then one is at least half-way to playing it anyway. Rave over!

So, basically, it means very little! Presumably, you've listened to the song. That will most likely give far more clues than blindly following what someone has tabbed. Seriously!

That apart, if you're learning piano, it's somewhat counter-productive to try to translate guitar tab (especially as you don't play guitar!). You will be better off finding proper piano music, and learning to translate that. Honest!

Comment: I take your point about proper piano music, but if I like a particular song, and want to play along on piano with the aim of ultimately singing it too, and it's not a massively well known song, then generally the piano part isn't available anywhere.  I can work it out by ear, slowly, but it's often very useful to see what notes the guitar is playing.  I'm actually writing a little computer script to process the tab and output which notes it should be on piano and this will help with that.

Comment: Another thing i've noticed about Tab is that it's more of a memory aid than an actual score.  That is, unlike sheet music, you can't read it religiously and translate it into music.  it's more like an aid to helping you work out the chords, and then you have to do the timing yourself, which is easy to do by ear.    So it's kind of akin to song lyrics, actually, in that they tell you the important stuff but don't tell you how to sing it.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - that pretty well sums it up. Persevere with the ear, it'll pay off in the end (or well before that!) and chances are you'll understand my scepticism concerning a lot of tabs. Never understood why tab writers don't use, say, 16 or 32 'zones', which would pretty well cover most songs, albeit occasionally in a primitive way - but better than it is now.

Comment: x means mute the string, not 'don't play'.

Comment: In most - maybe all? of the tabs I've seen, each vertical does relate to a division of the bar, so they do show the timing. The dashes therefore do mean 'don't play' in the sense of 'don't pick/strum the string *at that time*'. I don't doubt that you may have seen more bad tabs than I have!

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica - if you mean the vertical lines represent bar lines, then yes, that's (usually) true. That hardly helps with the timing of individual notes, though, which is (one of ) my beefs.And yes, the dashes must be there to say 'there's nthing here to play' - but they don't signify silence or  held notes. So, they're not that self explanatory.

Comment: @dissemin8or - really don't want to get embroiled, but some x mean a particular note in the middle of a chord's fingering gets muted so it doesn't even get heard, can't help hitting it, but hopefully it won't add to the chord notes; but other x mean actually play the string muted so it **does** make a sound. More than a contradiction!

Comment: @Tim No, I'm agreeing with you that tab writers should use (say) 16 zones (or whatever's appropriate for the song), but saying that in my experience, they really do! Certainly that's how I write tabs, and the tabs I've come across seem to have been written like that too - meaning that the characters that line up vertically at one time position (whether numbers, or just '-' dashes) really do represent a well-defined time point (aside from considerations like 'feel' or slight degrees of swing, which even SN doesn't show).

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica -0.k. the one shown here has 36 segments, for wont of a better term, but the guitar part on the track starts on beat one. So why are there two segments empty before the numbers? And a lot of tabs I've seen have a couple of segments (dashes) *before* any first number, again not making sense. Just looked at a tab for happy b'day, and the timing was all over the place - not even an anacrucis!

Comment: @Tim I do also tend to find most things on Ultimate Guitar need fixing!

Comment: @MaxWilliams Before you waste hours of your time writing that computer script, download the free version of Sibelius (called Sibelius First) and you can do this in one Alt + Click. You can also do it with Copy + Paste. Sibelius will automatically translate any tab into standard notation on the staff of your choice, in any clef.

Comment: Also, @MaxWilliams proper tab includes rhythmic stems and (if written properly) can offer valuable information not found easily on a standard staff. For example, where specifically on the fingerboard to play the passage. Most melodies and chords can be played in multiple places on guitar, and only after years of experience might you know the best option for economy of motion and optimal results.

Comment: @NickGrooves - that much is so true. Why is it, then, that even my students question why certain passages have to be played in certain places, having found more suitable ones? And it does restrict fingerboard knowledge. One *ought* to be able to play the same passage in several places (otherwise one wouldn't know that the tab shown is best or not). If Brian May had relied on tab, when he broke a string at a concert, he'd have been stuffed. As it was, he knew other places, and no-one noticed!. And - is Sibelius prone to using the optimum places? How does it know? (If it can go the other way).

Comment: I think Tab is best viewed simply as an *aid* to learning a song, for people who already know what it sounds like, and is not to be looked into too deeply.  If you're getting really detailed with it you should probably be using sheet music - that is the way to prescribe exactly what to play.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - back in the 60s, I used to buy the sheet music - still have a load - and it really wasn't that helpful. Over time, I found it was easiest to listen to a track, and figure out first key, then sort of scale used,then chords, then voila! It put me in good stead for when students come and say they want to learn 'this piece' in this lesson. So it had to be done 'on the fly'. And also is invaluable when I'm in a house band at open mics, etc. Often the dots/chords are approximations - as are tabs...

Comment: @Tim I agree, I think it's best to go by ear generally, but sheet music and tab can save you some time.  I just meant that sheet music tends to be more in-depth than tab, really.

Comment: @Tim From my Sibelius experience (been using since 1997) it seems to prefer as many open strings and stay as close to open position as possible, but adjusting it is exceedingly fast and simple. Highlight the passage + down/up arrow to the proper string. Sibelius automatically adjusts the fret number to match. It will also put tab into standard notation / works both ways, so if you have tab and want the shape notes, it's two keystrokes away.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Standard notation (shape notes) is essential, absolutely. But there are some details which are much easier for guitarists to glean from Tab, which is why most serious books include both staves. I started reading on piano and get a lot of theatre work as one of the few guitarists in Atlanta who is a fluent reader. I definitely appreciate and prefer shape notes. But I learned most of the 1,000+ pop/rock/blues songs I know by ear, and having taught for about 20 years I appreciate how Tab and aural skills benefit the student. All my kids learn how to read and appreciate both systems.

Answer (score 2):

The dashes represent lines.  They are not meant to each be an individual symbol; they arise from trying to represent guitar tab using only typed symbols.  Take a look at printed tablature:

[image: Sample tab for House of the Rising Sun]

[Image source](https://guitarcontrol.com/beginner/easy-guitar-tabs-for-beginners/)

There is a 6-lined staff on which the fret number for each note is placed.

Comment: That tab is so inaccurate! For starters, in the Animals version, the top string gets played in every bar. thus 7 notes played, often. For seconds, the last note played, in most bars, is open 3rd (listen to youtube!), as the guitarist couldn't change chords quickly enough. Yet another reason I don't trust tab...  If tis is related to my recent question, I'm referring to tab with dashes, not solid lines looking like clefs.

Comment: @Tim an import detail in the tab in the question is that it is plain text file, not an image. How would you represent solid lines in a plain text file?

Comment: @ojs - even so, the tab is a poor representation of what actually was played on the original track. If one is going to portray such, it's important (to me, at least) to get it accurate! Dashes or lines are the least of the mistakes here.

Comment: @Tim I agree that this is a very bad transcription. But the context of the discussion was really the dashes or lines.